# How to convert SQL to LINQ where it contains IN keyword in statement

Tags: sql, .net, linq

I have got this SQL statement which I am trying to convert to LINQ.

```
SELECT * 
FROM History 
WHERE Status = 'Created' AND HistoryId IN (1, 2, 3);
```

I have not been able to do the IN part. Tried following but I am unable to complete it:

```
var list = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3};
var result = db.History.Where(x => x.Status == 'Created' && )
```

How do I write IN part of SQL in LINQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=net-7.0):

```
var result = db.History.Where(x => x.Status == 'Created' && list.Contains(x.HistoryId))
```

Comment: I would also make replace list with a HashSet, so "Contains" is O(1) instead of O(n).

Comment: @StasIvanov Does it matter if the contains is not actually executed, but converted to TSQL ?

Comment: @sgmoore If it's converted correctly then there is no difference. But I am not sure if every LINQ-to-SQL provider is smart enough to convert this. Probably, this needs to be checked.

Comment: Agree with @sgmoore, we're operating on expression trees level here and all that needs to be done is to convert such tree with `Contains` operator into a SQL statement so anyway all list elements have to be retrieved